# The most simple LINQ to XML query. But I can't get it

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm new to LINQ. My XML:

```
<Config>
<remainingDays>7</remainingDays>
</Config>
```

How to get 7 using LINQ?

I've tried the following and none helps:

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("Config.xml");
remainDay = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Element("remainingDays").Value);
remainDay = Convert.ToInt32((from ele in doc.Elements()
                             let e = ele.Element("remainingDays")
                             select e));
remainDay = Convert.ToInt32((from el in doc.Descendants("remainingDays")
                            select el).First());
```

Updated.
remainDay is a int. I want to get the value of day in XML and assign to remainDay

Comment: What is `remainingDays`, the element seems to `day` as in the sample provided ?

Comment: Don't know if it's from XDocument and if it is the answer but lose `.Value` --> `(int)doc.Element("remainingDays")`

Comment: remainDay is a int. I want to get the value of day in XML and assign to remainDay

Comment: It would also be helpful if you stated what exactly the problem is. Do you get an exception? Do you get the wrong value?

Comment: something like `.Descendants("day").FirstOrDefault().Value;` like should work for you

Comment: I tried : XElement doc = XElement.Load("Config.xml");
remainDay = Convert.ToInt32(doc.Element("remainingDays").Value); and it works just fine... are you sure the file path is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc.Descendants("remainingDays").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

This will help you get the value `7`, Now you can parse it using `int.Parse` and assign to remainDay.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
var config = XElement.Load("Config.xml");
var remainingDaysElement = config.Elements("remainingDays").First();
var remainingDays = int.Parse(remainingDaysElement.Value);
```

off the top of my head.

Comment: Can I use XElement rather than XDocument?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(store.OpenFile(_strXMLFile, FileMode.Open)))
   {
      XDocument _xDoc = XDocument.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());
      _strDays = _xDoc.Element("Config").Element("remainingDays").Value;
      return _strDays;
    }
```

and define using System.Xml.Linq; 
that's it.

Comment: Can I use XElement rather than XDocument?

Comment: just change this line _strDays = _xDoc.Element("remainingDays").Value;